# Graded lex and graded reverse lex

Tags: polynomials

I just want to know what the difference between graded lex and graded reverse lex is. For example, if we have
\begin{equation}
f=3x^4 y - 2x^2 y^3 z + 7x^2 y z^3 - x^3 y^2 z + z^3 y^3 - 6x^3 yz^2
\end{equation}

I know that if we have a graded rev lex with z>x>y we have that the lead term (LT) of $f$ will be $7x^2 y z^3$, what would LT$(f)$ be with graded lex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are graded, so for both you choose the largest total degree first, the lex and revlex stuff is only used if you need to break a tie.

If $y < x < z$ then for lex you look at the variables in the order $z \to x \to y$ (largest to smallest) and choose the *largest* degree, moving on to the next variable if you need to break a tie.  So among those terms with total degree $6$ (the largest) we choose $7x^2yz^3$ because we look at $z$ first and choose the term with the largest $z$-degree.

If we still have $y < x < z$ then for revlex you look at the variables in the order $y \to x \to z$ (smallest to largest) and you choose the *smallest* degree, moving on to the next variable if you need to break a tie.  So among those terms with total degree $6$ we would take $\mathrm{LT}(f) = 7x^2yz^3$ because the smallest $y$-degree you can get is $1$, and of the two monomials that have that $y$-degree the smallest $x$-degree you can get is $2$.

It's a little funny because the leading term comes out to be the same.  To see one that comes out different let $f = x^2 + zy$.  Keep $y < x < z$.  Then with graded lex we have $\mathrm{LT}(f) = yz$ and with graded revlex we have $\mathrm{LT}(f) = x^2$.

To keep them straight think that the "l" in lex is for large, and reverse large is small, so:

- **lex** $\to$ **largest** variable first, take **largest** degree
- **revlex** $\to$ **smallest** variable first, take **smallest** degree

Comment: Ok I think I get what you're saying. So say for example if I were to apply gr lex on $f$ then we would get $7x^2 y z^3 - 6x^3 yz^2 - x^3 y^2 z - 2x^2 y^3 z + z^3 y^3 +3x^4 y$ since if the degrees of the terms are the same we look at the degree of $y$ first right?

Comment: I mean we look at $z$ first then $x$ then $y$. But if it was gr rev lex would the only difference be swapping the $z^3 y^3$ term with $-2x^2 y^3 z$?

Comment: Yes, swapping those two terms is the only difference.

Comment: Ok I think I am getting the hang of this. Thank you very much for your explanation, it has helped me understand this a lot further

Comment: I read that a matrix monomial ordering is a total ordering if we have $Ker A \cap \mathbb Z^n=0$ (where $A$ is the matrix), can you please tell me why is that?

Answer (score 0):

That's right: one must inspect the monomials of highest total degree with indeterminats ordered by decreasing weights. For two monomials $m=z^{\alpha}x^{\beta}y^{\gamma}$ and $m'z^{\alpha'}x^{\beta'}y^{\gamma'}$, one has $m>m'$ if for the first differing exponent, *starting from the right*, $m$ has the *smallest*. So , by decreasing order, we have:

$$z^3x^2y\succ z^2x^3y\succ zx^3y^2\succ z^3y^3\succ zx^2y^3\succ x^4y$$

Comment: I read that a matrix monomial ordering is a total ordering if we have $Ker A \cap \mathbb Z^n=0$ (where $A$ is the matrix), can you please tell me why is that?